# How can i change background on item click in overflow?

Tags: android, android-layout, drawable, menuitem

So in my MainActivity, I can change the background of the layout by clicking on the overflow in my actionbar and selecting a background.

But how can I change the layout across all other activities?

**This is the code i have now**

```
private int selectedBackgroundId = R.id.defaultTheme;
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.defaultTheme:
            mainLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.defaultbackground);
            if (selectedBackgroundId == R.id.defaultTheme){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Background already set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Background set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            selectedBackgroundId = R.id.defaultTheme;
            return true;
        case R.id.background1:
            mainLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.redpinkgradientbackground);
            if (selectedBackgroundId == R.id.background1){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Background already set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Background set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            selectedBackgroundId = R.id.background1;
            return true;
```

**Second question i have**

How can I save the layout that has been set when app is destroyed?
So when I reopen the app, it's still the layout I clicked in the overflow menu.

Comment: mainLayout is null, did you reference before change the background?

Comment: changing the background for mainLayout works, but for the second layout in my other activity it doesn't. I want both layouts to have the same background.

Comment: then songActivityLayout is null , put the complete class in the question

Comment: when i remove this line,             songActivityLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.redpinkgradientbackground);
Everything works

Comment: put your activity and the layout

Comment: added the full class

Comment: put the layout xml

Comment: i have 2 layout files, with each a relative layout with the id's mainLayout and songActivityLayout.

Comment: you are using this layout: setContentView(R.layout.display_songs) , if that layout doesn't contains songActivityLayout , it will crash

Comment: So how can i fix this?

Comment: I don't know what do you want, usually is one layout per activity

Comment: so when a user starts my app, they can choose a background, but when the go to another activity, the background is gone, i want both activity layouts to have the same background the user clicked.

Comment: you can do something like this when a user sets a background on one activity save meta data in preference and then use that meta data in other activity on create to check which background is set or choosen and then you can apply the same

Comment: like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16008918/how-to-change-background-color-across-activities

Comment: you can change it easily, you have to just make Linear Layout public static and set colour where you use a click on overflow and remember you have to also change the colour of other unselected linea layout as normal color .and

Comment: and how can i save the background that has been set by the user when the app is destroyed?

Comment: can't make a linear layout public static, i get the message that we can't place android context classes in static fields